# Reading from a text file to populate an array

Tags: c++, arrays, filestream

The goal I am going for is to store values into a text file, and then populate an array from reading a text file.

At the moment, I store values into a text file;

```
Pentagon.CalculateVertices();//caculates the vertices of a pentagon

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("vertices.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    myfile << IntToString(Pentagon.v[i].x) + IntToString(Pentagon.v[i].y) + "\n";
}
myfile.close();
```

I have stored the values into this text file, now I want to populate an array from the text file created;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    Pentagon.v[i].x = //read from text file
    Pentagon.v[i].y = //read from text file
}
```

this is all I have for now; can someone tell me how you can achieve what the code says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert `int` to `std::string` nor `char*`.

```
myfile << Pentagon.v[i].x << Pentagon.v[i].y << "\n";
// this will add a space between x and y coordinates
```

Read like this:

```
myfile >> Pentagon.v[i].x >> Pentagon.v[i].y;
```

`<<` and `>>` operators are the basics of streams, how come you haven't come across it?

You could also have a custom format, like `[x ; y]` (spaces can be omitted).

Writing:

```
myfile << "[" << Pentagon.v[i].x << ";" << Pentagon.v[i].y << "]\n";
```

Reading:

```
char left_bracket, separator, right_bracket;
myfile >> left_bracket >> Pentagon.v[i].x >> separator << Pentagon.v[i].y >> right_bracket;

// you can check whether the input has the required formatting
// (simpler for single-character separators)
if(left_bracket != '[' || separator != ';' || right_bracket != ']')
    // error
```

Comment: So in order for me to store values in a text file, they can be any 'type'? They do not need to be strings? 

I come from a background, where the basics were skipped.

Comment: They could accept even custom classes if you overload the operators.

Comment: That makes sense, or we would not be able to have complex programs. 

A question, ">>" is giving me errors., do I need

Comment: @Moynul Have you used std namespace etc?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan At the top I have 'using namespace std' to let the compiler know in advance.

Comment: Pentagon is a class I assume. Why not using its instance?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan  Pentagon is a struct, my naming conventions are bad, I apologise for that. To read from a file, will i need to use an 'ifStream' object? Like in java, you have your input, and output stream objects.

Comment: @LogicStuff ticked answered for the explanation, and the "custom format". Many thanks.